# Was Alter Mysterious Heroine X's third form inspired from Star Wars?

Tags: fate-grand-order

In Fate/Grand Order, Alter Mysterious Heroine X's 3rd stage looks like this

[image: Alter Mysterious Heroine X 3rd stage]

to me she looks very much like a Sith Lord from Star Wars because

- The Sith often wore black hoods
- Alter Mysterious Heroine X's Excalibur looks like a Red Light Saber
- She looks like she is using Force Lightning
- She has eyes like that of [The Emperor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ok5mR.jpg) and [Anikin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73UIU.jpg)

So I am wondering, was Alter Mysterious Heroine X's third form inspired from Star Wars?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the [Mysterious Heroine X (Alter)](http://fategrandorder.wikia.com/wiki/Mysterious_Heroine_X_(Alter)), this form is indeed based on being a Sith Lord!

> オルト・ライトニング (Alter Lightning) and her double-bladed lightsaber is a parody of Red Lightning and the double-bladed lightsaber used by Darth Maul in Star Wars.

You can see this [double-bladed attack](https://youtu.be/SOXVDpR-I00?t=20) on Youtube

This is due to the fact that, prior to the English release in June 2017, there was a [Saber Wars Event](http://fategrandorder.wikia.com/wiki/Saber_Wars_Event) in January 2016 for the JP release. This appears to be a parody based on the release of Star Wars: The Force Awakens in December 2015

[image]